# How to hide a Graph with button in Quarto?

Tags: r, button, show-hide, quarto

I was wondering if it is possible to hide a graph with a button like you can do this with a code chunk using `code-fold: true`. Is there a similar way for graphs? Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
title: "How to hide graph by button"
format: 
  html:
    code-fold: true
engine: knitr
---

Example code:

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see you can use a button called "Code" to hide the code chunk. Is there a way to do this only for the graph in `Quarto`?

Comment: May be using a little bit of javascript? (since  I am not finding any direct yaml or chunk option to do this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a little bit of javascript we can achieve this in `Quarto`.

````
---
title: "How to hide graph by button"
format: 
  html:
    code-fold: true
    include-after-body: graph_fold.html
engine: knitr
---

Example code:

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec, y = mpg)) + geom_point()

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()

print("Its not a graph")
```
````

**graph_fold.html**

```
<script>
function graph_fold() {
    cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell:has(img)");
    cells.forEach(cell => {
      imgs = cell.querySelectorAll(".cell-output-display:has(p img)");
      imgs.forEach(img => {
        det = document.createElement("details");
        sum = document.createElement("summary");
        det.appendChild(sum);
        det.children[0].innerText = "Graph";
        img_clone = img.cloneNode(true);
        det.appendChild(img_clone);
        cell.replaceChild(det, img);
      });
    });
}

window.onload = graph_fold();  
</script>
```

---

[image: graph folding button]

---

[image: code folding button and graph folding button works similarly]

---